# What could be causing throughput issues?

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, bandwidth

I'm experiencing some crazy issues regarding my internet speed using Ubuntu 15.04. I can't get anything greater than 10Mbps down,but I'm achieve 30 Mbps up.

My laptop doesn't have an Ethernet port, but uses a Intel 7260 Dual Band wireless card. I figured that this card was the source of all my problems. 
Usually they are 4 sources of internet issues.

ISP level, Router Level, Driver Level, Hardware Level.

But I haven't been able to narrow it down. My ISP is fios and every other device in the house performance is great. It is not the router, as once again other wireless devices are having no issues.

So I'm thinking it must be the driver or hardware, the wireless card is prone to issues in Ubuntu and Windows. However I had a Sony WLan adapter and I figured I would use that until I replace the card. Well the performance still is the same, around 10 Mbps down and 30 Mbps up.

I have never seen anything like this.

Also in Connection Information the speed says 130 Mbps, but the actually throughput still stays under 10Mbps.

Comment: What speed service do you actually have from FIOS, and how are you testing it exactly?

Comment: I think we have around 75 Mbps down and up. I test it using multiple online speed test. Unfortunately I don't have an Ethernet port on my laptop to test it that way.

Comment: Well, I have a 7260 AC/BT4.0 card in my laptop, and while it rarely matches the speed test on my workstation that's connected with gigabit ethernet, I do get ~300 Mbps up/down on my FiOS 500/500 connection, on wifi. On my workstation's gigabit.

Answer (score 0):

So this answer help me.

https://askubuntu.com/a/638554/491662

> Turn off bluetooth (use rfkill or turn off in Bios)
>   Turn OFF 802.11n mode (in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf add options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1)
>   Turn ON link aggregation (in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf add options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8)
>   Turn OFF watchdog (in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf add options iwlwifi wd_disable=1)
>   Turn off power saving features ($ sudo iw wlan0 set power_save off)
>   Set regulatory domain ($ sudo iw reg set )

<strike>All my research has me to believe that bluetooth is a major culprit. For instance I realize this problems didn't start until I started using a pair of bluetooth headphones with my laptop. Also If I follow those instructions but skipped turning of bluetooth, the performance will increase until a bluetooth device is connected.</strike>

I still don't know why bluetooth would only interfere with the download speed and not the upload speed.

As suggested , bluetooth isn't the main culprit

I have made another change which as dramatically improved performance. The router supplied by Fios has two internal wireless access points. One operates at 2.4 GHz and is (b,g,n capable) while the other operates at 5 GHz (n,ac capable). They were set to the same SSID. Once I changed the ID my connection to the routers says at around 130-200 Mbps.

There still might be another problem, on other ac capable routers I get around 500 Mbps. But my actual bandwidth from FIOS is no where near that, and I'm not doing any local networking stuff some I'm fine with this improvement.

Comment: Bluetooth is almost certainly not the culprit, especially if the exact same issue is replicated with a different USB wifi adapter. That sounds more like some other issue. If you want highest speed, you need to ensure you're connected on 5GHz, not 2.4GHz. My 7260 also seems to have some funky power management which causes the connected speed to jump around like crazy at times.